# Sitecore Treelist - How to select all child items into selected list(left to right window) based on parent selection?

Tags: tree-list

I'm working on `Treelist` field and have to select all children items at a time (like select all option) to selected list from `Treelist` (left to right window).

Is there any default option there or do we need to create new custom field?

Comment: Do you want always all children?

Answer (score 1):

The default Treelist does not support selecting all children at the same time.

If you are going to create your own control, be mindful of the implications of selecting all of your children's nested children - they could amount to a large number of items. Perhaps your custom control could be configured to only "Select All" the 1st level children.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Emanuele. If I change the field type from Treelist to Multilist will it impact on any existing functionality? I hope Treelist and Multilist will store the id's with pipeline separated.  

Here Multilist field has default functionality with Select All and Deselect All options.

Comment: Yes Multilist will work, and indeed it stores the selected items with a list of IDs separated with the pipeline - you can verify this by viewing the Raw Values.

The only functionality you will lose is the ability to select the children's children, and potentially you will have to resort to Sitecore Query to populate your Multlist.

Comment: This is super help. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help. After you tried and verified it helped you, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Hi, did this work in the end?

Comment: Hey Emanuele, Yes everything working as expected.